# How to draw line below heading to the heading size with padding

Tags: html, css

I want to put an line below the heading to the heading size, if i use border-bottom then there will be no space between the line and the heading. so i need some other solutions.
[image: Style need to be like this]

```
 h2 {
    color: #0085c3;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 33px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 40px auto 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
h2::after {
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: You mean *`"I want you to put"`*. What have you tried so far? `text-align:center` on the parent and `display:inline-block;` on a child - with padding and border on the child element... Should not be hard! Where is your best attempt?

Comment: The image seems to be broken. It does not load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the `border-bottom` which is good, now you can use `padding-bottom` to add space. Something like this:

```css
h2 {
  color: #0085c3;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 40px auto 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0085c3;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>ADVERTISING</span></h2>
```

Comment: If i use fixed width size then larger heading will get affect @ Racil Hilan

Comment: You don't have to fix the size. I posted my answer before you added the code to your question, so I just provided an example. Now that I can see your code and the size issue that you're talking about, see my updated answer. Just add a `span` inside your header and set the `border-bottom` and `padding-bottom` on that span instead of the `h2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding with CSS in this way: `padding-bottom: 5px`.